# 500.html error page persist after cause of error is gone(page error handler using acs commons)

Tags: content-management-system, aem

I am testing a "page error handler" for 500 response using acs commons. I get a response written as 500 in (firefox --> webdeveloper) when I break the page. I do get the 500.html displayed. However, when I revert back the cause of the error and do a refresh, I still see the 500.html page displayed.

The cache.ttl and ttl has been set to 300 so I am trying after 5 mins only.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: It could be that your page is **browser**-cached.  Check the content-expires and cache-control headers set to when you initially get the 500.html page.  This is just a guess, but without more information it is hard to answer this definitively.

Comment: I have tried that in a private browsing setup as well. The issue persist there

Comment: It seems the issue is only with design dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using AEM 6. AEM 6 has this wiered issue where the JSP cache holds for a long time. Try applying the latest Service Pack, I guess it has the fix. This issue is not seen in AEM 6.1.

If the above is true, for now, go to the Felix Console http://localhost:4502/system/console/slingjsp and flush the JSP cache.

Comment: I use AEM service pack 2, is it a concern in this as well.